# Bootstrap-4.5 - Grid for mobile rows and columns

Tags: bootstrap-4, responsive-design, grid

I want to try fix this:

[image: My working design]

I'm using Bootstrap, and what I made is:

```
 <div class="card text-center">
  <div class="card-header" style="background-color: rgb(192, 193, 194);">
  </div>
  <div class="card-body">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-2">
          <h1 class="price-text font-weight-bold">${{asdasd}}</h1>
          <p>Reportado por: Fabrizio</p>
          <p>0 Confirmaciones</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-1">
          <div class="row">
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-success btn-circle btn-xs">CONFIRMAR</a>
          </div>
          <div class="row">
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-warning btn-circle btn-xs" 
              data-toggle="modal">
               ACTUALIZAR
            </a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-2">
          <h5 class="brand-text font-weight-bold text-left">{{ asdasd }}</h5>
          <p class="address-text text-left">{{ asdasd }}</p>
          <p class="address-text text-left">{{ asdsad }}</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-1 col-centered">
          5Kms
          <a target="_blank" href="#">
            <i class="material-icons md-36">room</i>
          </a> 
        </div>
      </div>                  
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I'm using col-xs because if I use just "col", I can't get good results... I'm developing this page, just for mobile phones for that reason I want to get the things order in the right place. I want to take the buttons on the right, and the same with the "5Kms room icon", center it.

Could you give me a hand?

Thanks!

Comment: Which version of Bootstrap are you using?

Comment: Hi @DavidLiang Bootstrap v4.5.2

Comment: Then there is no 'col-xs-*' class anymore. Use 'col-*' instead.

Comment: Yes I know that, for that reason I marked "I'm using col-xs because if I use just "col"". When I use just "col", the design breaks. @DavidLiang Thanks for your time

Comment: write your code on codepen for more detail

Answer (score 0):

I've already made with a workaround:

I post my answer just in case that is handy for someone else:

```
 <div class="col-xs-3">
  <div class="row">
    <a href="#">
      <i class="material-icons">check</i>
    </a>
    <a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#UpdatePrice" (click)="loadUpdatePriceData(station)">
      <i class="material-icons">priority_high</i>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

I've just use 1 row, not 2. And all is good.